# Be held Vs To be held

Tags: grammar, bare-infinitive

> He proposed that this meeting to be held annually instead of monthly.

Should *to* be omitted or kept?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: that question is about _be_ vs _are_, this one is about a different distinction. Although I cannot see why anyone would want to add _to_ to that sentence...

Comment: medica's 'The subjunctive clause can be a mandative subjunctive which is a clause following a mandative word (expressing a demand, requirement, request, recommendation or suggestion) and usually, but not always, begins with 'that' and **contains a bare infinitive**.'  [bolding mine] seems quite adequate to me. This question has _in essence_ been asked before and already has an answer.